# MySQL Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user error when connecting from Docker container to host machine

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-rds

I'm trying to run a Docker container that has EF Migrations in it against an RDS-hosted MySQL cluster.

To do this, I'm using AWS Session Manager to tunnel to the RDS instance from my host machine, and I've proved I can connect from the host machine using MySQL workbench.

I'm passing the connection string into the container by setting an environment variable and running the EF Migrations DLL. When I try to do this, I get the "Access denied for user" error.

I've opened a bash session on the container, installed mysql-shell and get the same error when trying to connect that way.

The container is run with network=host, and I've proved that's working by running an NGINX container on the host mapped to port 8080, and if I do `curl localhost 8080` from the EF Migrations container I get the HTML for the default NGINX page back.

I've queried the `mysql.users` table, and the host value for that user is `%`, so I shouldn't be getting blocked because of the host. However, the host is the only thing I can think of that could be blocking it. For some reason, the container seems to be resolving localhost to `172.21.0.1`.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?! I'm at a bit of a dead end.